# Filter a tuple and pass to another function 2 arguments

Tags: haskell, tuples

Hello I would like to filter a tuple and pass to another function 2 arguments, a `String` and an `Int` (not in tuple)

I've got these functions:

```
hasRated :: [Rating] -> String -> (Bool, Int)
hasRated [] username = (False, 0)
hasRated ((name, rate):xs) username
            | name == username && rate > 0 = (True, rate)
            | otherwise = hasRated xs username

listRatedFilms :: String -> Film -> (Bool, Int)
listRatedFilms username (t, d, y, r) = hasRated r username

displayFilmsRatings :: String -> Database -> String
displayFilmsRatings username database = displayRatedFilms (filter (listRatedFilms username) database)

displayRatedFilms :: Database -> Int -> String
displayRatedFilms database mark = concat(map displayRatedFilm database)
```

`listRatedFilms` returns a tuple `(Bool, Int)` i.e `(True, 4)`

Now I want to filter it if the `Bool` is `True` then pass the `Int` to the `displayRatedFilms`, if its `False` carry on filtering.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Could you provide the exact type of `listRatedFilms`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display for some, assuming: `getFilms :: Database -> [Film]` or whatever `Database` is.

```
displaySome :: String -> Database -> String
displaySome username database = unwords
                            . map (displayRatedFilms database . snd)
                            . filter fst
                            . map (listRatedFilms username)
                            . getFilms $ database
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Data.List module's `filter` method to filter out all the items that have `False` in the first position of the tuple like so:

```
haveRatings = filter (\(p, v) -> p) films
```

There's not much else I can suggest at this point though, since none of your methods return a list of any sort.